# Negotiating start date after accepting offer? [Entry - Level]

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, new-job, negotiation, employment

I'm a senior in college and I have accepted a job offer starting after graduation. However, now looking back on it, my start date is earlier than I would like it to be. (I know I should have negotiated this before accepting it but I want to see if I still can now). I am still ready and available to start on my current date but would like to see if I can have a later start date.

Is this something that I can still negotiate? Is it worth it to ask?

Comment: Did you already sign the employment contract?

Comment: I accepted the offer via email. Does that count as signing the actual contract?

Comment: It probably does count. Why don't you just ask them if you can move it?

Comment: Actually, an email offer is not the same as signing a contract. The latter is the only oficial document.

Comment: which country is this?

Comment: Related: [Is it appropriate to ask for an extra week before start date with new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42340/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-an-extra-week-before-start-date-with-new-job)

Comment: Thanks for the question! Country: US Graduation: June Ideal start date: September Given start date: July so I figure it might be a stretch

Answer (score 4):

I get this request a lot of times. Most organizations are flexible and will accommodate you. Some will look at this with suspicion that you are fishing for a better offer. So the question is, why do you need to extend? If you have a valid reason, there should not be a problem.
Another thing you can try is to join on the offered date and ask for a short vacation. Although most people are likely to deny such a request, if you can provide a good reason, you are likely to be told what's feasible. e.g. the HR may say you need to discuss with your manager, and they can connect you to him/her. As long as you can convince the manager with a reason, this may get approved.

That being said, there are times when this request may be declined. Some organizations have a pre-defined training plan for new grads which is quite expensive. Like you, there could be more hires and it may not be possible to move around those training's just to accommodate your late joining. Another possibility is that you are identified for a particular project / work. In that case, your boss may have to make a call. HR wont override business decision on the same.

If you are prepared for both scenario's, well there is no harm in asking. At most, someone is going to say no, you have to join on assigned date. Ask nicely, its worth a try :).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something that I can still negotiate? Is it worth it to ask?

Seems that you have **not actually signed any contract**, so there is a chance that you may renegotiate the start date.

However, I would do this ASAP so ther is a better chance you can make it. Write an email to your recruiter politely explaining your request. They can either say no or agree, the only way to know is asking.

I also advice you that you kindly remind them to sign the *actual* contract, as accepting an offer via email is not an official agreement, while a contract is. While you don't sign an actual contract I think there is still room for negotiations, but at the same time **nothing is legally bounding them** (or you) to carry out what they offered you, be careful there. Good luck with that.