# Start Date Negotiation

Tags: job-offer, start-date

I received a job offer where they asked if it would be possible to start earlier than I want. I asked if it is fine if I start a bit later and they said it should be fine. Should I just wait to hear what they say about the start date or should I start when they want me to start?

Comment: When you pushed back did you provide them with a specific date?  If you haven't time to propose one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it appropriate to ask for an extra week before start date with new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42340/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-an-extra-week-before-start-date-with-new-job)

Answer (score 1):

> I received a job offer

Which had a specific start date I assume.

Generally I've gotten a verbal offer contingent on a few things (background/credit/criminal check, HR approval, etc.) **and that was when** a start date was discussed.

Then the offer letter had the date we discussed.

> I asked if it is fine if I start a bit later and they said it should be fine.

"It should be fine" isn't a phrase I would be okay hearing regarding a start date.

You need something in writing stating when you will start (email is fine if **both** your new manager and HR are on the email).